# How to wire/configure two pubsub gcp projects in one spring boot application with spring cloud?

Tags: configuration, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-gcp

Currently, we're working on a spring boot application in a GCP project, which connects to a PubSub endpoint in the same GCP project, but also to a PubSub endpoint in *another* GCP project. I want to use plain spring cloud GCP PubSub components, but with those, I have no chance to set a second PubSub connection to a second GCP project. Also, if I would have one service account, with PubSubTemplate object I have no possibility to target a topic in another project than the current from the service account. Is the only way to implement/extend the PubSubAdmin/PubSubTemplate or is there also a solution like multiple connection and template for JPA databases?

Kind Regards
Sven

Answer (score 2):

Considering correct privileges for another project,you can publish/subscribe to topics in different projects with a fully qualified topic/subscription name

eg. for topic publish `pubSubTemplate.publish("projects/other-project/topics/the-topic", "payload")`.

This should be available with the latest `spring-cloud-gcp` version. Please see this [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1639) for more details.